# Writing to multiple files on Raspberry Pi 2 SD Card

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I understand trying to write to the same file from two different methods will cause an exception.  Is it okay to write to two different files on an SD Card at the same time or should I create a method for writing to the SD card and use a lock object to prevent multiple threads from accessing the method ?

Comment: Lukkha. I've tried both ways.  I know if I create a method with a lock then I am safe.  I am curious if I have two different methods writing to the same SD card on a Pi could cause problems ?